# how to connect Android app with local server XAMPP

Tags: android, xampp

I'm having problem with my android application that is connected to XAMPP . The application in the emulator was working fine because its in the same device . But when I downloaded the application in the android device . The application has been installed successfully but I couldn't sign in or log in . 
I think that happens because the server in the laptop has different ip address than the android device . 
I have tried many solutions like adding new port or closing firewalls but it didn't work .

does anyone have other solution ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's connected to your wifi, then hit your laptop address provided by the router. If it's connected to your mobile network, then first find out your router external IP address, then forward some port to that 10.0.2.2:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from your device.

If none of the above does not work then there is another solution which is `ngrok`. Go to https://ngrok.com/ and download the .exe file (for windows). Extract it somewhere and add its path to the PATH environment variable so that you can access it from cmd anywhere. After that simply use this command:

```
ngrok http 80
```

This will give you a url which maps to your localhost and can be accesed from any device in your house or not.Literally anywhere. Do not close cmd and then put the new URL in the Android Project-> Rebuild the project and voila! You can login from your device!!

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

- Find the IP of your computer in the network;
- Connect your Android device to the same network of your PC;
- From your Android device, go to the network settings and open the
  options of your connection;
- Show the advanced options;
- Choose "Manual" for the "Proxy" voice;
- Write the IP of your PC in "Proxy hostname" and write 8080 in the
  "Proxy port";
- Save the configuration and try to use your application: it should
  work now!